# How to setup ActiveMQ Artemis redelivery policy not to block the queue

Tags: jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

**Background**

I have a JMS message queue on Apache Artemis 2.7.0.redhat-00056. The broker is configured with a `redelivery-delay` of 10 minutes. If I publish a message to the queue and it fails on the consumer then it goes back to the queue as a scheduled message to be delivered in 10 minutes time. Any subsequent messages that are published are processed straightaway, so the queue is not blocked by the scheduled message.

If a number of messages are sent in quick succession then what happens is they all fail and get scheduled for 10 minutes time. In this case it looks like Artemis is  trying to preserve the message order.

**Documentation**

The docs on redelivery say the following:

> Other subsequent messages will be delivery regularly, only the cancelled message will be sent asynchronously back to the queue after the delay.

[Redelivery documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html)

**Problem**

It seems inconsistent to me that if you publish the messages in close succession that Artemis appears to preserve the order, whereas if there is a slight delay between messages then the queue does not block and only the failed messages are scheduled with a delay (as per the docs).

I'm trying to find a solution so that if one message fails and needs to be redelivered in 10 minutes that it doesn't block subsequent messages.

**Example**

It doesn't need anything special to recreate this. As described you just need to send some messages in quick succession to a queue that has a redelivery policy on the broker. I've been testing with a basic example as follows:

Spring boot app that produces five messages on startup.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ArtemisTestApplication
{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArtemisTestApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        send("Message1");
        send("Message2");
        send("Message3");
        send("Message4");
        send("Message5");
    }

    public void send(String msg)
    {
        logger.debug("Sending message :{}", msg);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("jms.queue.TestQueue", msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ArtemisTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Consume messages and throw an error to trigger the redelivery policy.

```
@Component
public class TestConsumer
{
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConsumer.class);

    @JmsListener(destination = "jms.queue.TestQueue")
    public void receive(TextMessage message) throws JMSException
    {
        logger.debug("Message received: {}", message.getText());
        throw new RuntimeException("Force redelivery policy");
    }
}
```

The app was generated using the [spring boot initializr](https://start.spring.io/). Other than giving it a name, the only thing of note selected was the artemis dependancy under messaging.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In application.properties I have configured the connection properties to the locally running instance of Artemis.

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=
spring.artemis.password=
```

And on the broker I have configured the queue with a redelivery policy. Note: I set the delay to 0 here and the problem still occurs in that all messages are blocked until the first message has had three attempts and been moved to the DLQ. If you change the delay to a positive number then you see all five messages are scheduled for delivery later.

```
<address-settings>      
    <address-setting match="jms.queue.TestQueue">            
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>                      
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>    
        <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
    </address-setting>    
  </address-settings>

<addresses>     
    <address name="DLQ">            
        <anycast>               
          <queue name="DLQ" />            
        </anycast>         
      </address>       
      <address name="jms.queue.TestQueue">            
        <anycast>               
          <queue name="jms.queue.TestQueue" />            
        </anycast>         
      </address>                      
</addresses>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this?

Comment: Also, you say, "In this case Artemis is trying to preserve the message order." What's your basis for this claim?

Comment: Among various articles I read yesterday I found something that said Artemis will try to preserve the order for messages sent by the same producer. Other than that it is anecdotal, I can see the group of messages using the listScheduledMessages operation and they are all scheduled for 10 minutes later, however, only the first was actually delivered and when the subsequent messages are eventually delivered the delivery count is 1. So it certainly behaves like it is preserving the order.

Comment: I've added an example as requested although tbh I don't see it helping much here. There is nothing special about the code, it's the most basic example of adding a few messages in quick succession and then consuming them with a redelivery policy. It's a question about how the queue works rather than my code.

Comment: Artemis will try to preserve the order of messages sent by the same producer because that's what the JMS specification expects. However, things like the redistribution or load-balancing of messages in a cluster or redelivery delay may change the order ultimately. All those situation are not addressed by the JMS specification.

Comment: Whether you send messages with slight delays between them or send them all at once shouldn't they all end up being redelivered since you throwing a `RuntimeException` every time you receive a message in order to force redelivery? It's not clear to me what other behavior you expect under these circumstances.

Comment: I believe you're seeing the expected behavior when you set `<redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>`. This configuration indicates that any message delivery which fails will be retried immediately before dispatching any of the messages behind it. If `redelivery-delay` is > 0 then the message will wait the configured amount of time before it is retried giving the messages behind it a chance to be delivered in the mean-time.

Comment: As far as the example code goes, it does help clarify the use-case quite a bit. While it is the broker's behavior that's in question here it helps a lot to understand what the client is doing to trigger that behavior.

Comment: Given that your example uses Spring and that the example should be *minimal* I assume you can't produce this problem without Spring (e.g. using the JMS API directly). Is that correct? Generally speaking, I avoid Spring when attempting to reproduce issues because it just adds another (somewhat thick) layer of behavior which can obfuscate the actual issue.

Comment: "shouldn't they all end up being redelivered" no because only the first is actually delivered, the other messages get scheduled for redelivery without actually being consumed. Once the first message is processed (moved to DLQ after x attempts) the next message is processed and the delivery count is 1, so it has gone through the process of being rescheduled with the first message but was never actually delivered.

Comment: "I assume you can't produce this problem without Spring" that's a big assumption, I don't think spring has anything to do with it. I only used boot because it's easy to write an example in a few lines of code and because our real project uses spring.

Comment: My assumption about what is required to reproduce the problem is based on what you've provided as a *minimal* example. As noted in the documentation I linked, a minimal example should, "Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem." Since you're using Spring I must assume that Spring is required to reproduce the problem. If Spring isn't required to reproduce the same problem then it shouldn't be included as part of the example since by definition it would not be a minimal example at that point. This is an important step in identifying the underlying issue.

Comment: I've had good luck reproducing problems using modified versions of the examples shipped with Artemis. There is already a "delayed-redelivery" example shipped with the broker in the examples/features/standard directory. These offer a good starting point because they're simple and easily reproducible. You just need to fork your version and push it to GitHub somewhere and then anybody can pull it down and run it.

Comment: I was about to have a go at modifying the delayed-redelivery example but someone has now done this work for me. I raised a ticket last week and they have replied to say they are experiencing the same problem including a code example. I knew spring wasn't the culprit because we had seen this working with an older version of AMQ (5.8) and because of the way the queue behaved (setting all messages to in delivery and then moving all to scheduled even though only the first increments the delivery count) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2417

Answer (score 3):

I have come to the conclusion that this is a bug with Artemis. I raised a ticket for this and a comment has been left with somebody else experiencing the same issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2417

In the mean time I have had to change our client application to handle the redelivery policy itself. If there is an error reading the message then we increment a counter on the message and write it as a new message with the required delay. The message being consumed is then acknowledged to unblock the queue and allow the other messages to be read. I have left the redelivery policy configured on the broker as a fall back in case there is an error outside of this logic or something not caught. It's not ideal but it is at least now meeting the requirements.

Comment: As noted on the JIRA, the current workaround is to set `consumerWindowSize=0` on the client's URL.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on the bug: ActiveMQ Classic have a switch to disable the same functionality, on the client side ActiveMQConnectionFactory:

`activeMqConnectionFactory.setNonBlockingRedelivery(true)`

The intention behind the observed behavior is to keep message ordering: Say the first message actually went through on the second attempt (the error was transient): To keep ordering between the messages on queue, you cannot deliver more messages until all attempts for the current message have been exhausted. For the [Mats3](https://mats3.io) *Message-Oriented Async RPC* library, this makes no sense, as it explicitly (and obviously, due to the library semantics) cannot guarantee ordering through a "Mats Flow" - so I was happy when I finally found that configuration parameter.

So, while this makes sense wrt. ordering of messages - in particular for the case where you have a single consumer for a queue - it would be great if Artemis also had such a feature to be able to turn this off, and just go right ahead and deliver the next message.

*(What ActiveMQ evidently does if nonblocking is enabled, is to put the rollbacked message "at the end of the prefetched messages list". If you have a bunch of poison messages in a row, and that number of messages exceeds the prefetch limit, it will still have to "stutter through" (attempt redelivery of) those messages before any new are fetched..)*